Boundedness assumption on Global Approximation Theorem of Sobolev space
The following is from Evan's PDE book, from pages 251 to 252.


I'm not sure why we needed the boundedness assumption on $U$.
Can't we just let $U_i = \{ x\in U \,|\, \text{dist}(x,\partial U)>1/i \text{ and } |x|<i \}$ to construct locally finite countable open coverings $\{V_i\}$ and $\{W_i\}$ of $U$, such that $V_i\subset\subset W_i \subset\subset U$?
I've read this question, but it just tells that the above construction of $U_i$ works for $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Can someone give a counterexample for the case of unbounded $U$?

You are right. Nothing prevents you from going to unbounded domains (functions in Sobolev space have decaying properties at infinity anyway). I do believe Evans opted for a presentation convenience here (per his foreword in the book). If you check the treatment in Adams's book Section 3, you will find that the argument is exactly like your construction of $U_i$. Check Theorem 3.16 (Meyers-Serrin Theorem) in Adams.
